# Why adding two identical addEventListeners to the same element are triggered/execute at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I am trying to tell the user to click two points on a canvas.
And I want to take the coordinates of those two points and draw a line between them. But I am encountering some errors.

I have added two event listeners in my drawLine function and in that function I need to get two sets of coordinates.

```js
const mainCanvas = document.querySelector('#mainCanvas');
const pExplain = document.querySelector('.explain');

function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
}

function drawLine() {
    pExplain.innerHTML = "Please select a starting point for your line";
    mainCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        getCursorPosition(mainCanvas, e);
        pExplain.innerHTML = "Please select an ending point for your line";
    })

    mainCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        getCursorPosition(mainCanvas, e);
        // and here draw the line
        // Do not worry about the line, I know how to draw it
    })
}
```

This is not working and it is giving the same set of coordinates twice.
Thank you for any help in advance.
Please be kind because I am a beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: Well you add two event listeners both get executed, and then you try to remove an eventlistener for a function that you never added.

Comment: Event listeners are usually added at the start, exactly once. You're trying to use them as "wait for a click, return the coordinates" type of mechanism, which won't work at all. You need to maintain a state in your program, which means having a `var` that stores the current mode. Is the user currently in "add line" mode? Is the user currently selecting the first or the second point? Your single event listener needs to check that state and act accordingly.

Comment: Here's a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2xnm4fuo/

Comment: Thank you for your comment it really helped. But I still have a question how could I track where the user is pointing and display a line on the screen from the initialX and initialY to place he is pointing his cursor; and all of that before he clicks the final position. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I added just one click listener and use a status field to determine which action to take.

```
const mainCanvas = document.querySelector('#mainCanvas');
const pExplain = document.querySelector('.explain');

function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
    return {x:x, y:y};
}

var status = "getStart";
var start, stop;
function mouseDrawHandler(e) {
        if(status == "getStart") {
            start = getCursorPosition(mainCanvas, e);
            pExplain.innerHTML = "Please select an ending point for your line";
            status = "getStop";
        } else if (status == "getStop"){
            stop = getCursorPosition(mainCanvas, e);
            addLine(start,stop);//for example
            status = "getStart";
        }
    }

function drawLine() {
    status = "getStart";
    pExplain.innerHTML = "Please select a starting point for your line";
    mainCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDrawHandler);
}

drawLine();
//mainCanvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseDrawHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it really helped. But I still have a question how could I track where the user is pointing and display a line on the screen from the initialX and initialY to place he is pointing his cursor; and all of that before he clicks the final position. Thank you